# How to bundle a native library (.so + .jar) for reuse in new Eclipse Android projects?

Tags: eclipse, jar, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have a C++ library and I made some JNI code to export it into the Android world. I also created an Android App which uses my JNI interface.

To use the library, I imported all the *.java and *.h / *.cpp files in my Eclipse App project (into the right folder), then I created the *.mk files for the NDK. I compiled the library with ndk-build and loaded it into the target device with Eclipse. The App works fine.

Now I would like to separate the App from the library. So, I compiled name.jar which contains the Java files of the JNI interface, then I compiled the libname.so with ndk-build for the C++ stuff. Then I put name.jar into newproject/libs and libname.so into newproject/libs/armeabi. Consider "newproject" the App I created without the library source code (I don't want to release the source code, only the .jar and .so).

The result is a crash of the  App with the memory dump into LogCat. I used System.loadLibrary("name") in a static context.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My procedure was OK. I found the problem: my app was loading the lib and it was running the C++ code. By the way the crash happened early on a socket() call. I had to set the INTERNET permission into the manifest file.

Comment: I create an application.application contains .so file.Now I want to make a single jar file that contains my apps code+.so file.Is it possible on android sdk.I do not use ndk.please let me know.

Comment: I think you only can do this with NDK. Look at: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html how to do